# pip produces warnings upon trying to install Django and setuptools- Xubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: xubuntu, python-2.7, django, pip

I'm trying to set up Django on my laptop for web development testing. When I run

```
sudo pip install Django
```

I get the following errors/warnings:

```
The directory '/home/aaron/.cache/pip/log' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the debug log has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want the -H flag.

The directory '/home/aaron/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the debug log has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want the -H flag.

The directory '/home/aaron/.cache/pip/log' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the debug log has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want the -H flag.
```

I also get the message:

```
Requirement already satisfied (user --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

`sudo pip install -U setuptools` elicits the same messages.

This could be because I've already installed it and don't remember doing so (I'm switching back and forth between frameworks to see what I like). Any ideas why this error would be occurring?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu/Xubuntu 14.04 and later, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

This will install Django 1.6.1. The latest release of Django that you get by installing it with pip is 1.7.3.

In order to prevent collisions when installing two or more different versions of the same Python package, you should be using Python virtual environment creator (*python-virtualenv*) from the default Ubuntu repositories. The virtualenv utility creates virtual Python instances, each invokable with its own Python executable. Each instance can have different sets of modules. Virtual Python instances can also be created without root access. You can install python-django from the Ubuntu Software Center in the usual way using `sudo apt-get install` and also another version of Django inside a Python virtual environment  without root access using `pip install`.